# How to stick a wildcard in a string in Python?

Tags: parsing, python-3.x, artificial-intelligence

I want to create a simple chatbot type program. After experimenting with  AIML, and finding it lacking, I decided to see if Python has a chance of working. I want to be able to take a sentence like

"What color is the sky?"

and respond with a intelligible answer. So, I want to use wildcard symbols with if/else statements to do it quickly in python. Something maybe like this:

```
statement = input()
if statement == "_ color _ sky":
    print(SKY_COLOR)
```

If you know of a library(hopefully built in:-]) that has a tool or even just a little escape character type trick, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Answers to this will vary wildly by the definition of "simple parsing program" and "reasonable answer", as well as the range of sentences you want to accept.

Comment: @Dannnno Probably:-) if you have an edit suggestion, lay it on me! I want my question to make sense. I am kinda new here, so any suggestions will be taken to heart.

Comment: Its less that I have a suggestion, and more that I think your requirements are ambiguous

Comment: @Dannnno Well, that's helpful... I can try to edit my question if you think I should, but if you _ambiguously_ tell me you don't like the way I phrased something, there's not much I can do.

Comment: Like I said, I think a "good" answer to this question depends on your definition of "simple parsing program" and "reasonable answer", as well as the range of sentences you want to accept.

Comment: @Dannnno Thanks for the suggestion! I appreciate the second opinion. Does this sound better? (a little late now,  I suppose)

Comment: That's better - based on those criteria I would agree with the answer that regex is probably the best and easiest way to handle this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regex matching seems to be what you want

```
>>> import re
>>> re.search(".*color.*sky.*", "where am I?") == None
True
>>> re.search(".*color.*sky.*", "what color is the sky") == None
False
>>> re.search(".*color.*sky.*", "what color is a rose") == None
True
```

it gives None if the pattern does not match.

Comment: Thanks! Works great! For those of you who need it, here is the documentation for RE: https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html